# Column misalignment with text & image in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see from the attached screenshot, if the first column has more text than the second, it causes a visual glitch.

How do I resolve this in Bootstrap?

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/oLderkuo/

[image]

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="portfolio-gallery row">

        <div class='gallery-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
            <span class='sub-gallery-icon'>
                <a href='#' >
                    <img width="300" height="200" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="gallery-thumb-img wp-post-image" alt="" />
                </a>
            </span>
            <span class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'><br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. 
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class='gallery-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
            <span class='sub-gallery-icon'>
                <a href='#' >
                    <img width="300" height="200" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="gallery-thumb-img wp-post-image" alt="" />
                </a>
            </span>
            <span class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'><br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class='gallery-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
            <span class='sub-gallery-icon'>
                <a href='#' >
                    <img width="300" height="200" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="gallery-thumb-img wp-post-image" alt="" />
                </a>
            </span>
            <span class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'><br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. 
            </span>
        </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code to get around this glitch.

You'll see I have 2 conditional statements below to cover large/medium size & small/x-small size.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Gallery
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

<?php the_content(); ?>

<div class="portfolio-gallery row">

<?php
$the_id = $post->ID;

$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 50,
'offset'        => 0,
'title_li'     => '',
'post_parent'  => $the_id,
'post_type'    => 'page',
'order_by' => 'menu_order',
);

$pages = get_posts( $args );

$output = '';

$i = 0;

foreach($pages as $value){

    $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( $value->ID, 'thumbnail', $attr = 'class=gallery-thumb-img' );
    $tcopy = get_post_meta($value->ID, 'gallery_short_description', true);
    $output .= "<div class='gallery-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4'><span class='sub-gallery-icon'>";
    $output .= "<a href='" . $value->post_name . "' >" . $thumb . "</a></span>";
    $output .= "<span class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'><a href='" . $value->post_name . "' >" .  $value->post_title . "</a><br />";
    $output .= " " . $tcopy . "</span></div>";

    if ($i == 2 || $i == 5 || $i == 8 || $i == 11) {
        $output .= '<div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div><div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>';
    }

    if ($i == 1 || $i == 3 || $i == 7 || $i == 9 || $i == 11 || $i == 13) {
        $output .= '<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div><div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>';
    }

    $i++;
} 

echo $output;
?>


<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery columns="0" size="thumbnail" link="file" itemtag="div" icontag="span" captiontag="span"]'); ?>

</div>

</div>

<br class="clear" />

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your text in `<p>` tag and set its width to `img` width
see the demo below:

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  margin: 10px;
}
p {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="portfolio-gallery row">

    <div class='gallery-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
      <span class='sub-gallery-icon'>
    <a href='#' >
     <img width="300" height="200" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="gallery-thumb-img wp-post-image" alt="" />
    </a>
   </span>
      <span class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'><br />
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. 
      </p></span>
    </div>

    <div class='gallery-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
      <span class='sub-gallery-icon'>
    <a href='#' >
     <img width="300" height="200" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="gallery-thumb-img wp-post-image" alt="" />
    </a>
   </span>
      <span class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'><br /> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      </p></span>
    </div>

    <div class='gallery-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
      <span class='sub-gallery-icon'>
    <a href='#' >
     <img width="300" height="200" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="gallery-thumb-img wp-post-image" alt="" />
    </a>
   </span>
      <span class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'><br /> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget leo leo. Sed sed pretium quam, ut bibendum libero. In semper arcu eget faucibus hendrerit. 
      </p></span>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Will this still work with responsive?

Comment: it will be better if you will give class to `p` tag like `<p class="description">` and then assign css like `.description{width:300px}`

Comment: I have tried here: https://jsfiddle.net/oLderkuo/5/ But the issue in the original screenshot still remains. Can you help?

Comment: let me check it

Comment: What do you mean by visual glitch?

Comment: I am unable to understand the issue correctly can you explain a bit more?

Comment: oh now I get the issue, the third image and text move to right instead of staying on left

Comment: Sorry, yes, I was just about to reply with this. I see some nice anonymous person has fixed here: https://jsfiddle.net/oLderkuo/3/ :-)

Comment: Nice work anonymous person, hey @michaelmcgurk can you post correct answer to this question with little explanation so it might help others having same issue?

Comment: Good idea sir - just working on a fix right now and will post solution - thank you for your help! :-)